# I can not receive any HEX data past 0x11

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am trying to control/communicate with a monitor by sending HEX commands via pySerial.

I can send commands to the monitor just fine and the monitor responds to them without a problem. When I try to receive the acknowledgement from the monitor that it is on or off, I only receive a portion of the response. Consistently the response printing terminates whenever a 0x11 is returned from the monitor and drops the HEX value in front of it.

Ex: 
Realterm returns: `0xAA 0xFF 0x00 0x03 0x41 0x11 0x01 0x55` 
My code returns:  `0xAA 0xFF 0x00 0x03 0x11` (Sometimes it returns a 0x01U at the end.)

I have tried receiving this data with xonxoff both set to False and True. I have also tested and altered all other parameters for serial.Serial(). When I communicate via a terminal application such as RealTerm, commands are received and the full response is printed. I currently have serial.Serial() set to the exact same parameters as what has been working in RealTerm. Anybody able to shed some light on this?

After reading through the forums I tried setting xonxoff to both 'True' and 'False' with no success

Searched around for a way to ignore `0x11` entirely so I can get the final HEX value (the only HEX value I really care about seeing).

Looked around the forums to see if a buffer is needed, but couldn't get that working either.

Made sure baudrate, parity, etc. all match settings currently working in RealTerm

```
import serial
from serial import SerialException
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, xonxoff=False, timeout=3.0, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False, bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, write_timeout=None, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, exclusive=None)
ser.isOpen()

command = b'\xAA\x11\x00\x00\x11'
ser.write(command)
s = ser.readline(8)
print(s)
```

I need the full HEX return value to show up. If nothing else, just the last HEX value. In the example in my description, that would be 0x55.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try `ser.readline()` or `ser.read(8)`